# Android EditText

Tags: android

in my custom listview that Contain an image and EditText ,and in EditText i can comment the photo ,i can give text comment max length of 50 ,when i lost the focus in EditText i want to rearrange the text in EditText in following format

EG: suppose comment contain 40 char and user can at a time directly view only 20 char,then if i lost the focus text should be rearranged that at the end there should be 3 dot

Original Comment i wirte:eg-> eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
after i lost focus it should shown as-> eeeeeeeee...

it's importent that the nothing happens to original text because these text i want to send to server, and i directly take these values,and if am replace the text by new this type of text this will create problem, also when i gain focus i need to see full text also.

NB: i set android:singleline=true

Answer (score 3):

Try android:ellipsize="end", or if you want to fade, try android:fadingEdge="horizontal"

Answer (score 0):

Use the `android:ellipsize="end"` in you XML layout file. You can also show the scrolling text by using `android:ellipsize="marquee"`.

Comment: in EditText the ellipsize has no effect